# Python, Find the drive letter with windows installed

Tags: python, winapi

I started making a program for fun when I encountered a problem. The problem was that I wanted to find the drive letter with windows installed on it (root drive). I assumed there was a function already made for that but I searched for a while and could not find one.

I wrote this code to do what I just described. Is this code redundant and am I being an idiot? There is probably a much easier way...

```
def root():

root = ""
i = 0
drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives = drives.split("\000")[:-1]

for i in range(0, len(drives)):
    drives[i] = drives[i].replace("\\", "/")

i = 0
for i in range(0, len(drives)):

    if os.path.exists(drives[i] + "Windows"):
        root = drives[i]
        break

return root
```

I suppose someone can use this for testing purposes or what not.

Comment: You have available both `GetSystemDirectory` and `GetWindowsDirectory` - I imagine either to be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There is an environment variable `windir`. On my computer in contains "C:\Windows". You can read this variable by `os.getenv('WINDIR')` (refer to [python 2:os.getenv()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getenv) or [python 3:os.getenv()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv)).

Comment: Important to note that windows doesn't have to be installed to a directory called 'Windows'. Your solution is the only consistently reliable way to do it. As a side note: on python 3.5 you can also use `os.environ['windir']`.

Comment: `os.environ` is not restricted to python 3.5. Ist exists in python 2.7 as well ([python 2.7: os.envirion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ))

Comment: Since the goal is to get the **drive letter** that Windows is installed on, you should use the `systemdrive` environment variable instead of `windir`.